# Loop to determine whether digits of a number meet a condition (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement

So, I am trying to create a function that determines whether a number is 'tidy'. (i.e. Each digit in the given integer is greater than the one that came before it.)

I have successfully managed to convert the integer into an array. But when I loop through it, I don't get the desired `true` for tidy and `false`, if otherwise. I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

```
function tidyNumber(n){
  var arr = n.toString(10).split("").map(function(t){return parseInt(t)});
  let tof;

  if(arr.length == 1){
    return true;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] <= arr[i+1]){
      tof = true;
    } else if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
      tof = false;
   }
  }
  return tof;
}
```

Comment: When `i` is `arr.length - 1`, the comparison will compare `arr[i]` to `undefined`.

Comment: You should return false immediatly when `arr[i] > arr[i+1]`, because with your algorithm, the number `1324` would be tidy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:  The reason your function does not return the desired result is that is only returns the last value of `tof`.  So your function currently only reports whether the last two digits of a number are tidy.  To use the example of @Seblor, `1324`:

1. First, the code will check whether `1 < 3` and set `tof = true`.
2. Next, it will check whether `3 < 2` and set `tof = false`.
3. Next, it will check whether `2 < 4` and set `tof = true`.  This erases the actual result that you were seeking.
4. Incidentally, the code will finally check whether `4 < undefined` (as @Pointy mentioned) but will not change the value of `tof` since neither conditional expression was satisfied.

You can achieve the desired behavior by returning the `false` result immediately when `tof = false` (as @nina-scholz suggested).  Here is what that might look like within your code:

```
function tidyNumber(n){
  var arr = n.toString(10).split("").map(function(t){return parseInt(t)});
  let tof;

  if(arr.length == 1){
    return true;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] <= arr[i+1]){
      tof = true;
    } else if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
      tof = false;
      return tof; // <-- Added return statement here
   }
  }
  return tof;
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you everyone. This was awesome! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad you thought so, @thelacaning!  Please mark one of the answers as the "accepted" answer.

Comment: Thanks, @thelacaning, for marking an accepted answer - another way to show gratitude/appreciation is to upvote any and all answers that you found helpful.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You could check only if a previous digit is greater than the actual digit and exit the function with `false`.

Then you need to start at index `1` and prevent checking a not given index.

```js
function tidyNumber(n) {
    var arr = Array.from(n.toString(), Number),
        i;                                      // declare, otherwise its a global variable

    for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(tidyNumber(1234));     //  true
console.log(tidyNumber(1));        //  true
console.log(tidyNumber(1223334));  //  true
console.log(tidyNumber(51223334)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
function tidyNumber(n){
    current = 0;
    while(n){
        if(current > n % 10){
            return false;
        }
        current = n % 10;
        n = parseInt(n / 10);
    }
    return true;
}
```

The idea is to by "% 10" to get the remainder of a division by 10. This will get you the last digit. Look if its smaller then the one before, else loop until the number is zero!